# Summarizing a dataframe in R with multiple functions in place?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new to R and trying to summarize a dataframe with multiple functions and I would like the result to appear in the same column, rather than in separated columns for each function. For example, my data set looks something like this

```
data =  
  A  B
  ----
  1  2
  2  2
  3  2
  4  2
```

And I call `summarize_all(data, c(min, max))` the dataframe becomes

```
a_fn1 b_fn1 a_fn2 b_fn2
    1     2     4     2
```

How can I make it so that the result of the summarize_all becomes this:

```
  A  B
  ----
  1  2
  4  2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(apply(data,2,min),apply(data,2,max))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      A     B
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
2     4     2
```

Comment: This does work! And how could I use this in a dplyr pipe?

Comment: @Anonymous, you can try `apply(data,2,min) %>% bind_rows(apply(data,2,max))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `transpose`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df1, cols = everything()) %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    summarise(min = min(value), max = max(value)) %>% 
    data.table::transpose(., make.names = 'name')
  A B
1 1 2
2 4 2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = 1:4, B = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```